# Make function CRUD DeletebyID(id) Javascript by its number of id not by index

Tags: javascript, function, crud

Heloo, i am new in learning of javascript. Can you guys help me..
Here's the detail:

I have arrays:

```
let todos = [
    {id: 1, todo: "learning javascript"},
    {id: 2, todo: "sleeping"},
    {id: 3, todo: "playing"},
];
```

All i have to do, I want to remove an array object that have number of id:2 by its id (exactly id/number) which is by "number" of value of the object. NOT by index. I want to make CRUD function. But the function only have one parameter, which is ID :

```
DeleteByID(id) ---> by its number id, not by index.
```

So, the result will become like this:

```
   let todos = [
        {id: 1, todo: "learning javascript"},
        {id: 3, todo: "playing"},
    ];
```

I've already tried my code below..

```
  function deleteByID(id) {
  for(var i in todos){
    if(todos[i].id == id){
      todos[i].splice(i, id);
      break;
    }
  }
}


    console.log("Delete:", deleteByID(2));
```

I've tried my code, but it doesn't work. I've tried to googling, but I still dont have any clue for the solution. Please help me guys. Thanks

Comment: "it doesn't work" ... what does it do instead of working?

Comment: you'll want `return todos.splice(i, 1);` ... to `splice` `1` element at `todos` at position `i` and return the spliced entry

Comment: my code is wrong. I dont have any clue that is matched with the logic of javascript.

Comment: yes, your code is wrong ... did you notice the **error** it produces in the console? that would be *useful information* ... anyway, see previous comment for solution

Comment: i want to erase one of row objects which had id number 2. It is exactly what i want for my code.

Comment: did you notice the error message in the console that your code produces?

Comment: okayv i will try

Comment: did you notice the error message in the console that your code produces? I keep saying this because it's debugging 101 ... check for errors in the developer tools console

Comment: when i try the code below : 
  
let todos = [
    {id: 1, todo: "learning javascript"},
    {id: 2, todo: "sleeping"},
    {id: 3, todo: "playing"},
];


 function deleteByID(id) {
      for(var i in todos){
        if(todos[i].id == id){
          return todos.splice(i, id);
        }
      }
      return todos;
    }


    console.log("Delete:", deleteByID(2)); 

the array goes to erase object id 1, not id 2 

Delete:
(2)[
{
id:
2
todo:
sleeping
}
{
id:
3
todo:
playing
}
]

Comment: have you not read the answer I posted 3 comments ago? you want to splice ***ONE*** element from the Array, not "id" Elements

Answer (score 2):

You want to splice todos, not todos[i] and you want to remove 1 element, not "id" elements

and you want to return the spliced element

Here you go

```js
let todos = [{
    id: 1,
    todo: "learning javascript"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    todo: "sleeping"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    todo: "playing"
  },
];

function deleteByID(id) {
  for (var i in todos) {
    if (todos[i].id == id) {
      return todos.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log("Delete:", deleteByID(2));
console.log("Todos:", todos);
```

Comment: don't bother, it works - I only ever post answers that work :p

Comment: yess.. i using visual code and jsconsole.com to validate the code :)

Comment: oh, I meant the browser developer tools console that shows errors in the browser ... but, if you want to use complex external tools that clearly didn't show the error your code has, go ahead

Comment: I didnt use dom to print in google developer tools. I've just using jsconsole and visualcode :D

Comment: and how well did that work? you didn't even know your code was throwing an error on `todos[i].splice(i, id);`

Comment: this code doesn't throw any errors @FirstyUkhtiMolyndi - I'm uncertain of the pertinence or the rationalisation for your elucidation

Comment: I mean the console nor shows exactly what i want. it shows todos[i].splice is not a function when I am using my code above.

Comment: you can open www.jsconsole.com and try my code

Comment: @FirstyUkhtiMolyndi - that's correct, because `todos[i].splice` is NOT a function ... `todos[i]` is an Object, not an Array - so, your console was telling you the correct thing

Comment: that's right thanks bravo for explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```js
let todos = [
    {id: 1, todo: "learning javascript"},
    {id: 2, todo: "sleeping"},
    {id: 3, todo: "playing"},
];

function deleteById(datas, id){
    let index = datas.findIndex(data => data.id === id)
  datas.splice(index, 1)
}

console.log(todos)
deleteById(todos, 2)
console.log(todos)
```

Comment: you're assuming a modern browser :p I like your answer better, though, I'd `return datas.splice(index, 1)`